# Remove an element from the results after querying. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say I have a database table Bananas. I can get all the bananas from the query

```
@bananas = Bananas.all
```

now @bananas is an Array of all rows in the table. Now, I want to remove the default primary key 'id' from each of the element of the array. Not from the table but from the @bananas array. How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select` to select the attributes you want to retain; Do not include `id` in the list below to remove that.

```
@bananas = Banana.select("size, color")
```

**EDIT:**

`@bananas = Banana.select(Banana.column_names.reject {|x| x.eql?('id')})`

Comment: Added alternative for that above. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any way to parse @bananas and remove id from it??

Comment: `@bananas` will be the array of objects. You can do that `@bananas.map {|x| x.attributes.reject {|y| y.eql?('id') } }`. Though, I'll never recommend that; Since the outcome won't be an ActiveRecord Banana object anymore; it will be an attributes' hash

Comment: @polurupraveen..why do you want to remove id so badly. If you do not need it, just dont use it. I dont see any reason for you to do all these just for excluding id.

Comment: I'm designing an Api. So I want to keep it clean